# How can to create a JavaScript Hello World in a Mule component

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am trying to build a simple script inside a Mule component but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to get me started.

The [JavaScript Component Reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JavaScript+Component+Reference) shares no ideas on how to get something simple to run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

[image: JavaScript in a Mule Component]

You send a JSON encoded array and the script will return you the sum. Simple!

There is the flow:

```
<flow name="calculateFlow1" doc:name="calculateFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8089" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <scripting:component doc:name="JavaScript">
        <scripting:script engine="JavaScript">
            <scripting:text><![CDATA[
                var a = eval('(' + payload + ')');
                for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < a.length; sum += a[i++]);
                message.setPayload(sum + "");
                result = message;
        ]]></scripting:text>

        </scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
</flow>
```

Variables already given by Mule: `message`, `payload`.

Comment: Can you do 100% of the code in js in a Mule project?

Comment: That would be a question which you should ask separately.

Comment: why do you need eval('('

Comment: @SuperUberDuper - it is probably not needed, feel free to give it a try without and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In Anypoint Studio there is now a Script component:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/script-component-reference

...within which you can run scripts written in javascript.

1. Create your HTTP listener and allow GET
2. Drop in your Script component include your document.write "hello world" and deploy/run.
3. Call it in your browser and you're done.

Comment: so you can avoid Java and Groovy entirely?